# return int in UIAlertAction or return int after UIAlertAction

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

I would like to return an integer in a UIAlertAction.
Right now I get the error 'Int is not convertible to Void.' The function the alert is in is supposed to return int.

Here is my code:

```
func writeSteps() -> Int {
    var allergies = 0

    var severe = UIAlertController(title: "More information", message: "blablabla", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    severe.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

         allergies += 1
         return allergies


    }))

    severe.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
         allergies += 2
         return allergies

    }))
    self.presentViewController(severe, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Is this possible?

If not, whenever I try to return something after the uiAlertController, it returns that first, and then the uialert appears. Is there a way to make the uialert go first and then return a variable?

Comment: The problem here is that you're returning from within a closure / a different scope. For all intent and purposes, you should consider those closures as a completely different function. You either need to return from outside the closure, or return the var via a closure.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How could i do that? Everything that I put outside of the severe.addAction() runs before the addAction runs, so the variables aren't updated correctly. I tried adding '-> Int' before the 'in' in the closures and it says that it can't find member 'Default'

Comment: Keep a reference to the property you're trying to update (`self.allergies`) which you can then increment in your actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply trying to update the value in `allergies` you could keep a reference to the property you're trying to update (self.allergies) which you can then increment in your actions.

If you need to return this value, you could call a second method within your handlers:

```
severe.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
     self.returnAllergiesWithVal(2);
}))
```

Where the `returnAllergiesWithVal` method can then pass that value on to wherever you need it.